# Change window title

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nswindow

How do you change the title of an `NSWindow` instance? I have one window in a NIB; how can this be accomplished?

Comment: @Josh... a very useful post ... thnx for sharing ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code belongs in a controller class. In Interface Builder (or Xcode, depending on the version you're running), hook up the button you want to an IBAction that calls `-setTitle:` on your `NSWindow` instance.